# PHP - Define a constant and use it in a variable name

Tags: php, constants, variable-names

please can you help me in this problem? 
If in PHP I have a defined constant, can I use that constant name within a variable name?
For example how can I do something like the following in valid php syntax?

```
define ("HELLO", "hello-you");
$var_HELLO = "something";
echo $var_HELLO;
```

where HELLO in the variable name is the defined constant.

many thanks.

Comment: That's a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen. Why would you need to define a variable name using a constant?

Comment: i don't see the use of this but oh well

Comment: Don't. Please, just don't!

Comment: I use variables for many scopes as html nav, url links, etc... and I add every time same prefixes in a very great number of these variables. Maybe this can reduce the "maintenance nightmare"... @Quentin. And however it is also my curiosity that wants to know it :)

Comment: Use associative arrays if you want to group a bunch of variables together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely have to do this,

```
define ("HELLO", "hello-you");
$var_{HELLO} = "something";
echo $var_{HELLO};
```